# Products only appear when saved in Magento

Tags: product, import

I have imported 3,000+ products into Magento successfully.

The products are all present and correct in the back end.

But none of the products appear in the front end.

All the products are:

- Visible in Catalog.
- Enabled.
- Have a stock quantity of 10.
- In Stock.
- Assigned various Categories.
- Assigned to the correct website.

I have refreshed my Cache and Indices, just to make sure. But the products do not appear on the front end at all.

---

Here are the columns used in my CSV file:

`status`, `type`, `attribute_set`, `tax_class_id`, `visibility`, `qty`, `is_in_stock`, `product_id`, `name`, `short_description`, `description`, `rrp`, `weight`, `mpn`, `gtin`, `sku`, `price`, `color_text`, `size`, `stock_weight`, `category_ids`, `brand`, `small_image`

---

**But there is a solution!**

If I view a product in Magento's back end, and simply hit `Save`, it appears on the front end.

Does anyone have a better solution for me, than opening up all 3000+ products and hitting save on each one of them?

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to solve this, is to write a script that will re-save all your items.

```
set_time_limit(0);

// require magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// execute on admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku() . '<br/>';
}
```

*Please keep in mind that the next time you import items you may run into this issue again.*