# Products appear 'In Stock' only after re-saving

Tags: magento2.2, catalog, products

Certain products are listed as 'Out of Stock' on the front-end till I manually open the product and hit save.

Sometimes it's configurable products, but most often it's one or two simple products. I only find out about this when a customer complains that the size they want is not available. Any suggestions on how I can proactively detect these issues and fix them?

This issue seems to be the same but unsure which version it's referring to: [Products only appear when saved in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72930/products-only-appear-when-saved-in-magento)